# Tableau: Background color based axis value

Tags: tableau-api

I want to color background based on axis value in tableau as in below image:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have your Viz setup...

1. click on the Analytics Tab (top right next to the Data Tab)
2. drag Distribution Band onto the Viz and drop it on the Table element
3. set the values for the 2 band breaks (looks like ~33% and 68%)
4. click the 'Fill Above' and 'Fill Below' checkboxes in the middle Formatting section
5. click the 'Fill' dropdown and select the color palette you want

You can also create [custom color palettes](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/v2019.1/pro/desktop/en-us/formatting_create_custom_colors.htm) if the defaults do not meet your needs.